# Group slice by subarray values in Go

Tags: go, slice

I have an array of subarrays in the following format

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [unit_id] => 6504
            [assignment_name] => Grade assignment 
            [assignment_description] => 
            [assignment_total_score] => 10
            [unit_type_name] => Homework
            [is_graded] => 1
            [standard_id] => 1219
            [scoring_type] => score
            [attempt_score] => 8
            [unit_duedate] => 2016-02-10 09:00:00
            [standard] => Array
                (
           
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [unit_id] => 6504
                            [is_formal] => 1
                            [assignment_name] => Grade assignment 
                            [assignment_description] => 
                            [standard_id] => 1220
                            [standard_name] => 9-10.RL.3
                            [standard_description] => Analyze how complex characters (e.g., those with multiple or conflicting motivations) develop over the course of a 
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [unit_id] => 8584
            [assignment_name] => Sine and Cosecant Graphs
            [assignment_description] => Define the sine and cosecant graphs using a unit circle
            [assignment_total_score] => 15
            [unit_type_name] => Paper
            [scoring_type] => score
            [attempt_score] => 0
            [unit_duedate] => 2016-04-29 09:00:00
            [standard] => Array
                (

                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [unit_id] => 8584
                            [is_formal] => 1
                            [assignment_name] => Sine and Cosecant Graphs
                            [assignment_description] => Define the sine and cosecant graphs using a unit circle
                            [assignment_total_score] => 15
                            [standard_id] => 82790
                            [standard_name] => 9-10.RL.7
      

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [unit_id] => 11611
            [assignment_name] => Adding 5 + 3 + 6
            [assignment_description] => 
            [assignment_total_score] => 10
            [unit_type_name] => Homework
            [standard_id] => 82772
            [scoring_type] => score
            [attempt_score] => 0
            [unit_duedate] => 2016-08-23 19:00:00
            [standard] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [unit_id] => 11611
                            [is_formal] => 1
                            [assignment_name] => Adding 5 + 3 + 6
                            [assignment_description] => 
                            [assignment_total_score] => 10
                            [standard_id] => 82772
                            [standard_name] => 9-10.RL.1

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

And I would like to group it into a new slice based on the `unit_type_name` field in each subarray.

How can I group the slice by `unit_type_name`? Is there any native Go functions are available to do this?
if I for loop the above then I will get a duplicate one, how can I avoid that?

Comment: I'm right that this is a php array?

Comment: yes it is php array but same data is fetching using go lang.... how can I group based on the unit_type_name ?

Comment: What do you mean by "group the slice"? Do you want to sort them? Do you want to put them in new slices? What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: It would help if you minimize your code sample to an absolute minimum. It's hard to scroll & follow all those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think Go has a built-in functionality to help you do that (I may be wrong). My Assumption is that the PHP array will be converted to a JSON object. I managed to get the code below to help you sort your array (In JSON format) a based on the `unit_type_name`
I created two structs which have JSON values similar to what the array keys would be

```
//StandardType ...
type StandardType struct {
    UnitID                int    `json:"unit_id"`
    IsFormal              int    `json:"is_formal"`
    AssignmentName        string `json:"assignment_name"`
    AssignmentDescription string `json:"assignment_description"`
    StandardID            int    `json:"standard_id"`
    StandardName          string `json:"standard_name"`
    StandardDescription   string `json:"standard_description"`
}

//AutoGenerated ...
type AutoGenerated struct {
    UnitID                int            `json:"unit_id"`
    AssignmentName        string         `json:"assignment_name"`
    AssignmentDescription string         `json:"assignment_description"`
    AssignmentTotalScore  int            `json:"assignment_total_score"`
    UnitTypeName          string         `json:"unit_type_name"`
    IsGraded              int            `json:"is_graded"`
    StandardID            int            `json:"standard_id"`
    ScoringType           string         `json:"scoring_type"`
    AttemptScore          int            `json:"attempt_score"`
    UnitDuedate           string         `json:"unit_duedate"`
    Standard              []StandardType `json:"standard"`
}
var jsonData = ``
func main() { 
    m := []AutoGenerated{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonData), &m)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

I created a map to hold the `unit_type_name` keys

```
    sliceKeys := make(map[string]string)
```

I created also map to hold the arrays that have similar `unit_type_name` keys in an AutoGenerated array

```
    groupedSlices := make(map[string][]AutoGenerated)
```

Then I loop through the decoded JSON string searching for the unit_type_name

```
    for i := range m {
```

If a unit_type_name already exists in the key slice I add the array item to the group slice

```
      if _, ok := sliceKeys[m[i].UnitTypeName]; ok {
        autogenerated := groupedSlices[m[i].UnitTypeName]
        autogenerated = append(autogenerated, m[i])
        groupedSlices[m[i].UnitTypeName] = autogenerated
      } else {
```

Else I create a new array key and add the item to it

```
        sliceKeys[m[i].UnitTypeName] = m[i].UnitTypeName
        autogenerated := []AutoGenerated{}
        autogenerated = append(autogenerated, m[i])
        groupedSlices[m[i].UnitTypeName] = autogenerated
     }
  }
  fmt.Println(sliceKeys)
  fmt.Println(groupedSlices)
}
```

input:

```
[{"unit_id": 6504,"assignment_name": "Grade assignment","assignment_description": "","assignment_total_score": 10,"unit_type_name": "Homework","is_graded": 1,"standard_id": 1219,
"scoring_type": "score","attempt_score": 8,"unit_duedate": "2016-02-10 09:00:00",
"standard": [{"unit_id": 6504,"is_formal": 1,"assignment_name": "Grade assignment","assignment_description": "",
"standard_id": 1220,"standard_name": "9-10.RL.3","standard_description": "Analyze how complex characters (e.g., those with multiple or conflicting motivations) develop over the course of a "
}]},{"unit_id": 6504,"assignment_name": "Grade assignment","assignment_description": "","assignment_total_score": 10,
"unit_type_name": "Paper","is_graded": 1,"standard_id": 1219,"scoring_type": "score","attempt_score": 8,"unit_duedate": "2016-02-10 09:00:00","standard": [{"unit_id": 6504,"is_formal": 1,"assignment_name": "Grade assignment","assignment_description": "","standard_id": 1220,"standard_name": "9-10.RL.3","standard_description": "Analyze how complex characters (e.g., those with multiple or conflicting motivations) develop over the course of a "}]},{
"unit_id": 6504,"assignment_name": "Grade assignment","assignment_description": "",
"assignment_total_score": 10,"unit_type_name": "Aything else","is_graded": 1,"standard_id": 1219,
"scoring_type": "score","attempt_score": 8,"unit_duedate": "2016-02-10 09:00:00","standard": [{
"unit_id": 6504,"is_formal": 1,"assignment_name": "Grade assignment","assignment_description": "","standard_id": 1220,
"standard_name": "9-10.RL.3","standard_description": "Analyze how complex characters (e.g., those with multiple or conflicting motivations) develop over the course of a "}]}]
```

output:

```
map[Homework:Homework Paper:Paper Aything else:Aything else]

map[
Homework:[
{6504 Grade assignment  10 Homework 1 1219 score 8 2016-02-10 09:00:00 [{6504 1 Grade assignment  1220 9-10.RL.3 Analyze how complex characters (e.g., those with multiple or conflicting motivations) develop over the course of a }]}
] 

Paper:[
{6504 Grade assignment  10 Paper 1 1219 score 8 2016-02-10 09:00:00 [{6504 1 Grade assignment  1220 9-10.RL.3 Analyze how complex characters (e.g., those with multiple or conflicting motivations) develop over the course of a }]}
] 

Aything else:[
{6504 Grade assignment  10 Aything else 1 1219 score 8 2016-02-10 09:00:00 [{6504 1 Grade assignment  1220 9-10.RL.3 Analyze how complex characters (e.g., those with multiple or conflicting motivations) develop over the course of a }]}]
```

]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general GroupBy function I wrote:

```
// Created by BaiJiFeiLong@gmail.com at 2021/8/27 10:51
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "strconv"
)

func GroupBy(arr interface{}, groupFunc interface{}) interface{} {
    groupMap := reflect.MakeMap(reflect.MapOf(reflect.TypeOf(groupFunc).Out(0), reflect.TypeOf(arr)))
    for i := 0; i < reflect.ValueOf(arr).Len(); i++ {
        groupPivot := reflect.ValueOf(groupFunc).Call([]reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(arr).Index(i)})[0]
        if !groupMap.MapIndex(groupPivot).IsValid() {
            groupMap.SetMapIndex(groupPivot, reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.SliceOf(reflect.TypeOf(arr).Elem()), 0, 0))
        }
        groupMap.SetMapIndex(groupPivot, reflect.Append(groupMap.MapIndex(groupPivot), reflect.ValueOf(arr).Index(i)))
    }
    return groupMap.Interface()
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(GroupBy([]int{1, 22, 3, 44, 555}, func(value int) string {
        return strconv.Itoa(len(strconv.Itoa(value)))
    }))
}
```

The output:

```
map[1:[1 3] 2:[22 44] 3:[555]]
```

For your question, it shoube be some code like:

```
group := GroupBy(items, func(item Item) string {
    return item.UnitTypeName
}).(map[string][]Item)
```